# Converting strings to integers and adding them in Java

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion

I have 4 strings:

```
 str1 = 10110011;(length of all string is:32)
 str2 = 00110000;
 str3 = 01011000;
 str4 = 11110000;
```

In my project I have to add these string and the result should be:

```
result[1] = str1[1]+str2[1]+str3[1]+str4[1];
```

`result` should be obtained as addition of integer numbers.

For the example above, `result = 22341011`

I know **integer to string** conversion in Java is very easy but I found **string to integer** conversion a little harder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

Comment: thanks for answer. I forget to say that my length of string is 32. then integer.valueOf() doesn't works. :(

Comment: Are you actually trying to convert binary to integers? Do the strings only contain 0 and 1? Do they represent signed or unsigned numbers? Do the numbers fit in an int? The maximum number of an int is 2 billion and some, so a number of 32 characters does not fit in an int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To parse Integers `-2^31 < n < 2^31-1` use:

```
Integer value = Integer.valueOf("10110011");
```

For numbers that are larger, use the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class:

```
BigInteger value1 = new BigInteger("101100111011001110110011101100111011001110110011");
BigInteger value2 = // etc
BigInteger result = value1.add(value2).add(value3); //etc.
```

Comment: yes this is good answer but actually when string length is 32 then this doesn't works. @ggreiner

Comment: BigInteger is object? That means, i should define myself  or it is predefined object in java?

Comment: [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is a class, take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is with `Integer.parseInt(str1)`.  Returns an `int` containing the value represented by the string.

`valueOf()` returns an `Integer` object, rather than an `int` primitive.

Comment: but autoboxing will take care of that anyway so it's not a problem. `int x = Integer.valueOf("123");` will work just fine thanks to autoboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Because your numbers are so big they will not fit in an int. Use the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not known about your project and what actually your problem is. But I came to guess from  your partial information that, you have multiple set of strings in bit representation as you explained.

```
str1 = "1000110.....11";
str1 = "1110110.....01"; etc
```

adding those decimal values,gives an ambiguous result as an integer can be the sum of multiple integer values. Just see an example below where there are total 5 possibilities[with positive decimal values] to yield 6.

```
1+5 = 6;
2+4 = 6;
3+3 = 6;
4+2 = 6;
5+1 = 6;
```

If you proceed in that way you just do an error,nothing else in your case.
One better solution can be,
compute the decimal values of individual strings. Instead of adding(**+**) them, just concat(**join**) them to form a single string.
I am suggesting this approach because, This gives always a unique value and later you may need to know individual strings decimal values.

```
String strVal1 = String.format(computeDecimal(str1));
String strVal2 = String.format(computeDecimal(str2));
String strVal3 = String.format(computeDecimal(str3));
.
.
.
String strValn = String.format(computeDecimal(strn));

String myVal = String.concate(strVal1,strVal1,strVal1,....strValn);
```

Now you can treat your string as your wish.

```
//This will give you a non conflicting result.
```

Better to implement above approach than **[BigIntegers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)**.

Hope this helps you greatly.